# error message in plato

Tags: fortran, fortran90, plato

I am very new Fortran and I am doing some elementary practice. I have installed Plato latest edition. I found this program in the net, and try to compile it

```
program dotprod
  implicit none
  real :: c
  real, dimension(3) :: a, b
  print*,'Enter first vector'
  read*, a
  print*,'Enter second vector'
  read*, b
  c = a(1)*b(1) + a(2)*b(2) + a(3)*b(3)
  print*,'Dot product = ', c

end program dotprod
```

Plato shows no sign of error when I build and compile, but when I try to run the program the following error message shows up: the executable does not exist.

can anyone help me explain how to handle this error ?

thanks

Comment: you are using a commercial compiler, contact customer support it the installation docs are not adequate.

Comment: Start with a simple command line tool, there should be one also in Silverfrost. AFAIK it is gfortran in the  latest version.There is not enough info in your post to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your file name is too long. I had the same error message, and then I saved the file using another shorter name and suddenly it worked... I also tried your code and it works on my Plato (FTN95 Personal Edition (FTN95PE) version 7.20) on windows 10.